# HTMX hx:afterRequest event not calling

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, htmx

I need to call call some JS after having called an HTMX request, like this:

```
document.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', updateConnections())
```

In `updateConnections()` I need to reassign some references to html elements that may have been changed during the swap. It is running once on the initial reload of the page and then does nothing when HTMX requests are called in the page using hx-post and hx-get. What could be the problem?

The JS is for sure still running even after the HTMX requests, since other parts of the functionality still remains.

**EDIT: **
Here is the code now, and it still does not work:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    var hxCounter = 1

    function updateConnections() {
        console.log(`Reasigning the js references(${hxCounter})`)
        hxCounter += 1
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', updateConnections())
}
```

If it makes any difference I am using Django with HTMX and the JS is in a static file that is loaded into the base of the HTML, and should never change across the hx-requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the event on the body instead.

```
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', updateConnections())
```

Just be aware that because all events bubble to the `body`, any HTMX request will trigger `updateConnections()`. I hope that's what you need, otherwise you will need to listen to the event on the actual element making that particular HTMX request.

`EDIT`

The code works. You think it's not working because you are logging what should be the updated `hxCounter`. The problem in your code is that every time you make an HTMX request, hxCounter will be reset to 1 because you're redeclaring it. To demonstrate it, use the `let` keyword to define the `hxCounter` and you will see `SyntaxError: redeclaration of let hxCounter` error. The `var` keyword does not throw this error because it lets you do this.

To confirm that the event listener on the `body` is working, define (with `var`) hxCounter as an object rather than an integer.

```
var hxCounter = {count: 0}

// Then your function
function updateConnections() {
hxCounter.count += 1
console.log(hxCounter.count)
}

document.body.addEventListener("htmx:afterRequest", ()=> {updateConnections()})
```

Comment: It still does not work. The updateConnections calls once on page load and then does nothing as HTMX requests are being made.

Comment: It is working, you only think it is not. I edited the answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the event listener on the form or the element that sends the request.

sample:

```
<form hx-get="someurl" id="my_form">
  <!-- elements -->
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('my_form').addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest',updateConnections());
</script>
```